# What does it mean when Recommender Systems are making recommendations based on "static" data as opposed to "dynamic" recommender systems?

Tags: recommender-system

Much of new trends in recommender systems are based on giving recommendations taking into account changing user/services/items preferences or requirements. They mention, traditional recommenders make these recommendations on static data.

But, I am a little confused as to what this static data mean? Amazon makes recommendations to suit our preferences, isnt it? Is the problem of static data in it?

Nachiketa Sahoo and co-authors Param Vir Singh and Tridas Mukhopadhyay in their paper [“A Hidden Markov Model for Collaborative Filtering”](http://people.bu.edu/nachi/DynamicCollaborativeFiltering.pdf) explain about how commercial websites are suggesting recommendations based on past data and intend to create a more dynamic model to account for changing user requirements.

I want to simply understand

1. how traditional recommenders make these recommendations
2. what the context of "static" and "dynamic" data is
3. and how new research is helping to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance. (Any articles, research papers etc to support are welcome, but an explanation will help me alot)